# Pip & Conda : Pip installing in generic environement not conda

Tags: python, pip, conda

today I noticed that sometimes for no reason when I use pip to install a package inside a conda env it actually gets installed in my global env (python). I always ensure the env is activated and then use pip to install if the package is unavailable under conda install. Any explanation for this weird behavior since there is no error message and I only became aware of it after testing the concerned package. Here is the concerned package (but not the only one with which it happened, had it happen, with streamlit too).
This behavior is random: Sometimes it gets properly installed sometimes not.
[image]

Comment: I think you should check which `pip` you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One explanation would be that the environment isn't getting activated correctly. I've seen this happen in specific *terminal* contexts, in particular, with the VSCode and tmux terminals.

The most robust method for ensuring the proper `pip` is used is to not rely on shell state by instead using `conda run`. E.g.,

```bash
conda run -n ETC_tools python -m pip install PyPDF2
```

You may also want a `--live-stream` and/or `--no-capture-output` flag to observe real-time what `pip` is doing or respond to prompts. See `conda run --help`.

Comment: Correction : It does work only if i am on base env ( don't activate the target envs or else conda just freeze (my anaconda installation at least)). Thx for the answer.

Comment: @merv Thank you! I could not `pip install - e` my local package in my conda environment properly (I was getting: "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable" message). Using `conda run -n some_env pip install -e .` made it all work just fine!